# matplotlib hist gives me "too many values to unpack"

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to create a frequency plot of a sample whose values lie between -1 and 1.

creating the histogram using numpy works just fine:

```
freq, bins = np.histogram(sample, bins=np.arange(-1,1,0.05) )
```

but creating a plot using the same bins gives me an error (see title):

```
plt.hist(freq, range=bins)
```

In addition to this, how is it possible to adjust the x-labels such that the correct bin-values are shown?

**minimal working example:**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


if __name__ == "__main__":

  sample =  np.random.uniform(-1,1,100)
  freq, bins = np.histogram(sample, bins=np.arange(-1,1,0.05) )

  plt.figure()
  plt.hist(freq, range=bins)
  plt.show()
```

Comment: Please include the minimal example here, that pastebin link might expire.

Comment: what is this supposed to do? You do not pass the frequencies, but the sample to `plt.hist`.

Comment: You could answer the question yourself by writing an own answer in order to mark it as 'answered' or you can delete the question. However, a deleted question can not support others...

Answer (score 0):

It's not necessary to preprocess the data using numpy, just pass the data direct to matplotlib's hist function:

```
  sample =  np.random.uniform(-1,1,10000)
  #freq, bins = np.histogram(sample, bins=np.arange(-1,1,0.05) )

  plt.figure()
  plt.hist(sample, bins=100)
  plt.show()
```